# Strange question about exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been stumped for a while trying to figure out the flaw in this logic. Consider some positive, real x. Then

$$e^{ix} = e^{2\pi i\frac{x}{2\pi}} = (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{x}{2\pi}} = 1^{\frac{x}{2\pi}} = 1$$

I've felt like an idiot for hours. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps an analogy would be something like $(-1)^x = (-1)^{2\frac{x}{2}} = \left[(-1)^2\right]^{\frac{x}{2}} = 1^{\frac{x}{2}} = 1.$ I've simply written essentially the same string of equalities you've written using $e^{\pi i}$ in place of $e^{i}.$

Answer (score 0):

$z \to z^{\frac x {2\pi}}$ is a mutivalued function and just one of its values for $z=e^{2\pi i}$  is $e^{2\pi i\frac x {2\pi}}$. So you cannot conclude that $e^{ix}=1$.

To understand exactly what is happening you have to get familiar with logarithms in the complex plane.